# Updating SharePoint list lookup field with PowerShell is not working as expected

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have the following function, borrowed from [this module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SharePointSDK/1.1) by Tao Yang.

```
Function Add-SPListItem
{
  [OutputType('System.Int32')]
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'SMAConnection',Mandatory = $true,HelpMessage = 'Please specify the SMA / Azure Autoamtion connection object')][Object]$SPConnection,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'IndividualParameter',Mandatory = $true,HelpMessage = 'Please specify the request URL')][String]$SiteUrl,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,HelpMessage = 'Please specify the name of the list')][String]$ListName,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'IndividualParameter',Mandatory = $true,HelpMessage = 'Please specify the user credential to connect to the SharePoint or SharePoint Online site')][Alias('cred')]
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
    [System.Management.Automation.CredentialAttribute()]
    $Credential,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'IndividualParameter',Mandatory = $true,HelpMessage = 'Please specify if the site is a SharePoint Online site')][Alias('IsSPO')][boolean]$IsSharePointOnlineSite,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,HelpMessage = 'Please specify the value of each list field in a hash table')][Object]$ListFieldsValues
  )

  If($SPConnection)
  {
    $SPcredential = New-SPCredential -SPConnection $SPConnection
    $SiteUrl = $SPConnection.SharePointSiteURL
  } else 
  {
    $SPcredential = New-SPCredential -Credential $Credential -IsSharePointOnlineSite $IsSharePointOnlineSite
  }

  #Bind to site collection
  $Context = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext -ArgumentList ($SiteUrl)
  $Context.Credentials = $SPcredential

  #Retrieve list
  $List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
  $Context.Load($List)
  $Context.ExecuteQuery()

  #Adds an item to the list
  $ListItemInfo = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
  $item = $List.AddItem($ListItemInfo)
  Foreach ($Field in $ListFieldsValues.Keys)
  {
    $item["$Field"] = $ListFieldsValues.$Field
  }
  $item.Update()
  $Context.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

I'm trying to use the function to add an item to a SharePoint list with a lookup value from another list. This works well when I get the lookup value from another item in the same list, and just assign it to a new item. Like so:

```
$existingItem = Get-SPListItem -SiteUrl $siteURL -Credential $creds -IsSharePointOnlineSite $false -ListName $listToUpdate -ListItemId 480
$lookupField = $existingItem['serviceUcmdbID']
$newItemValues = @{Title='___test'; Objekttype='Test'; Objektnavn='Test'; 'serviceUcmdbID'=$lookupField}
Add-SPListItem -SiteUrl $siteURL -Credential $creds -IsSharePointOnlineSite $false -ListName $listToUpdate -ListFieldsValues $newItemValues
```

But I haven't figured out how to create `$lookupField` without getting it from an existing item. For instance, this fails:

```
$lookupField = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue
$lookupField.LookupId = 300
$newItemValues = @{Title='___test'; Objekttype='Test'; Objektnavn='Test'; 'serviceUcmdbID'=$lookupField}
Add-SPListItem -SiteUrl $siteURL -Credential $creds -IsSharePointOnlineSite $false -ListName $listToUpdate -ListFieldsValues $newItemValues
```

... with the following (partly Norwegian) exception:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Ugyldige data er brukt til å oppdatere listeelementet. Feltet du forsøker å oppdatere, kan være skrivebeskyttet."
At D:\Daniel\_TopsImport\SharePointSDK\SharePointSDK.psm1:232 char:3
+   $Context.ExecuteQuery()
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerException
```

The Norwegian part translates to: "Invalid data is used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read-only". The ID 300 from the above examples is the ID of an existing item in the reference list.

If I compare the `$lookupField` i got from another item and the one I created myself, they are of the same type, but they (unsurprisingly) differ in that one has a LookupValue and the other doesn't. But setting the lookupValue manually isn't possible, since `'LookupValue' is a ReadOnly property`.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Turns out you can just assign the ID directly, even though the field looks up another value in the reference table than the ID.

```
$id = 300
$newItemValues = @{Title='___test'; Objekttype='Test'; Objektnavn='Test'; 'serviceUcmdbID'=$id}
Add-SPListItem -SiteUrl $siteURL -Credential $creds -IsSharePointOnlineSite $false -ListName $listToUpdate -ListFieldsValues $newItemValues
```